# Why does this give me segmentation fault?

Tags: c++

I am following a course on Udemy and I just learned about smart pointers. This is my code for the challenge the section had-

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Test {
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out,const Test obj);
private:
    int data;
public:
    Test(int d = 0) : data(d)  {cout<<"Test constructor ("<<data<<")\n";}
    ~Test()  {cout<<"Test destructor ("<<data<<")\n";}
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out,const Test obj)  {

    out << obj.data;
return out;
}

unique_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<Test>>> create()  {

    unique_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<Test>>> p = make_unique<vector<shared_ptr<Test>>>();

return p;
}

void fill(vector<shared_ptr<Test>> &vec,int num)  {

    int data;
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        cout<<"Enter data ["<<i + 1<<"] :\n";
        cin>>data;
        shared_ptr<Test> temp = make_shared<Test>(data);
        //cout<<"Hello\n";
        vec.push_back(temp);
    }

return;
}

void display(vector<shared_ptr<Test>> &vec)  {

    for(const auto &a : vec) cout<<*a;

return;
}

int main()  {

    unique_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<Test>>> u1;
    cout<<"How many data points do you wish to enter?\n";
    int num;
    cin>>num;
    fill(*u1,num);
    display(*u1);

return 0;
}
```

Running this code gives me segmentation fault and I have figured out there is some problem in the void fill function, but I can't find a solution for it.

Comment: `u1` doesn't point to anything and you're dereferencing it.

Comment: You didn't think that there was a reason for `create`'s existence?

Comment: I should've put up u1 = create(); in the main

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that smart pointer `u1` doesn't point to any object and you're dereferencing it in the call expression `fill(*u1,num)` which leads to **undefined behavior**.

```
//---vvv-------->undefined behavior
fill(*u1,num);
```

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just **crash** which is what happens in your crash.

For example, [here](https://onlinegdb.com/V5qy6pi9Z) the program doesn't crash but [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iuqtUxHu8roxFlhY) it crashes.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>